# C# Create Const Array with multiple values at once

Tags: c#, arrays, static

I have class like below;

```
public class PhoneNumbersDto
{            
 public string code { get; set; }
 public int dial { get; set; }
 public string mask { get; set; }
 public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have Values like below;

```
 {
    "code": "TR",
    "dial": 90,
    "mask": "### ### ## ##",
    "name": "Turkey"
  },
  {
    "code": "TM",
    "dial": 993,
    "mask": "## ######",
    "name": "Turkmenistan"
  },
  {
    "code": "TC",
    "dial": 1649,
    "mask": "### ####",
    "name": "Turks & Caicos Islands"
  }
```

I want to create a static const array with TheseClassType but i couldn't initilize it.

Is there a way to create static or const array with multiple values at once.

Thank you

Comment: Why you can't initialize them? Any errors? Any examples?

Comment: I created an static array but only with one item. But i could'nt create with multiple array at once. I couldn't find soliton maybe i'm bad to search about solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static readonly PhoneNumbersDto[] array =
    {
        new PhoneNumbersDto()
        {
            code = "TR",
            dial = 90,
            mask = "### ### ## ##",
            name = "Turkey"
        },
        new PhoneNumbersDto()
        {
            code = "TM",
            dial = 993,
            mask = "## ######",
            name = "Turkmenistan"
        },
        new PhoneNumbersDto()
        {
            code = "TC",
            dial = 1649,
            mask = "### ####",
            name = "Turks & Caicos Islands"
        }
    };
```

As @eocron said, initialization can work; above is an example.  Though for better style, I recommend that you use a constructor taking these four inputs, rather than the style shown.

`readonly` is used in place of `const` - you can only declare compile-time items as constants.  readonly just means you can't edit the reference to this array.

Comment: For completeness, it should be pointed out that the array elements *can* be changed, even though the array reference itself cannot. If complete immutability is required, `ReadOnlyCollection<PhoneNumbersDto>` or a similar type should be used (which could be initialized from the expression shown here, except you would need an explicit `new`).

Comment: @madreflection: absolutely right.  There are a lot of design improvements that can be made here, including the decision of this being a static field in the first place.  Perhaps a method returning a ReadOnlyCollection could be better.  Hopefully this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: It's more about information (answer) improvement than anything to do with the design. You say that *"you can't edit the reference to this array"*, and you're correct, but a novice might incorrectly assume that the statement extends to array elements. So to prevent that assumption from lasting past that statement, it's good to point out the difference.